# What is Linux for VMS DCL "ON ERROR"?

Tags: shell, scripting, error-handling

Using [VMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenVMS) [DCL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DIGITAL_Command_Language) command scripts one can catch errors by using the `on error` command:

```
$ on error then goto MyErrorHandler
$ directory samiam.txt
$ delete x.txt
$ exit
$MyErrorHandler:
$ print "Something."
```

How does one do this in Linuxland?

In the example an error with `directory` or `delete` will cause control to go to `MyErrorHandler`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you want the [trap](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_12_02.html) function, specifically:

```
error_func() 
{
    echo 'An error occurred!'
    exit 1
}

trap error_func ERR
```

Errors later will jump to the function.  This is supported by at least bash, zsh, and ksh.